# I'm looking for a free database package for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, software-rec, database

I need to operate a database for personal use.  Now I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

As opposed to Windows operating system, I'm wondering if there's a dBase, Lotus123 or Access equivalent for Linux? Something simple like MS Works database would be ideal. Can someone point me to a suitable package?

Comment: Since you're using Ubuntu, you should have [Libreoffice Base](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/) installed by default. [Kexi](http://www.kexi-project.org/) might also be an interesting alternative. You might also want to clarify if you're looking for a database back-end (which the title might suggest), or a graphical database front-end (which your examples suggest).

Comment: Also, instead of giving examples of non-Unix/proprietary software (which many of us don't know anything about), you may want to specify what features you're after.

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous Open Source and free database options.

Popular choices are:

- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/) and it's successor [MariaDB](http://mariadb.org/)
- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/)
- ...

You can install them from the commandline with:

```
sudo apt-get install <mysql-server | mariadb-server | postgresql>
```

or using the GUI package manager aptitude

Comment: Even though the OP is asking for a database, if you look at the examples he lists, I suspect he might really be looking for a graphical database frontend.